# How to group by certain columns by sum with different grouping?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have users table with `termination_date` column that is either `NULL` if the users are active or it has a `datetime` if the users are not active anymore.

There is also a `termination_reason` column that describes why the user is not active anymore.

So for active users, it's `NULL` and if they are not active, then it has a value:

| id | country | city | termination_date | termination_reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sweden | Stockholm | 2022-10-04 | self |
| 2 | Sweden | Stockholm | 2020-03-20 | admin |
| 2 | Sweden | Stockholm | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | Switzerland | Bern | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | Switzerland | Bern | 2021-12-08 | admin |
| 5 | Switzerland | Bern | NULL | NULL |

I want to display information about active and non-active users grouped by country, city and termination reason (and show active users grouped by country and city only because they don't have `termination_reason`). But list the non-active users only from the past 12 months (and active of all time), so the above table would result in:

| country | city | active | not_active | termination_reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sweden | Stockholm | 1 | 1 | self |
| Sweden | Stockholm | 1 | 0 | admin |
| Switzerland | Bern | 2 | 0 | self |
| Switzerland | Bern | 2 | 1 | admin |

(Because the user terminated from Sweden and Stockholm is over 12 months ago)

I have tried the following query as suggested in the answer below, but it doesn't work, it doesn't count correctly (also there might be another approach without using `SUM`):

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE WHEN termination_date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS active,
  SUM(CASE WHEN termination_date IS NOT NULL AND termination_date BETWEEN ? AND ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS not_active,
  country, city, termination_reason
FROM user_data_table
GROUP BY country, city, termination_reason
HAVING termination_reason IS NOT NULL
```

I believe it also has something to do with the fact I'm summing a group with the `termination_reason` (because I want to group by it, however it affects the sum as well?)

This is also the reason for the title of this question - because I think I need to `SUM` the active users without the `termination_reason` group, and only then group by it

Comment: add filter termination_reason is not null - where termination_reason is not Null

Comment: But then it won't count the active users at all (I tried that and then the SUM of the active will always be 0)

Comment: can you please share sample data and expected result..

Comment: @LearnHadoop I edited the post entirely with more sample data and expected result

Comment: from your expected output , is it right entry ? Switzerland Bern 2 0 self.. couldn't find the entry self for bern

Comment: Yes you are correct it's confusing, what I mean is that it shows the active users for self and bern, but there is no "not active" entry that's why it's 0 there - there are 2 active users in Bern, and no "not active" users. You can just omit this row completely (I just wanted to show that the active column means active from the country and city group, because if it's not terminated, it doesn't have the `termination_reason` group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that you don't want to group the number of active users by the `termination_reason` and want this number to be the same for all rows with the same `country` and `city`. Therefore, you must calculate it independently from the grouping that includes the `termination_reason` column. You can do this with a sub-select in the SELECT list:

```sql
SELECT 
  ( SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM user_data_table
    WHERE country = U.country AND city = U.city AND end_date IS NULL
  ) AS active,
  SUM(CASE WHEN end_date IS NOT NULL AND end_date BETWEEN ? AND ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS not_active,
  country, city, termination_reason
FROM user_data_table U
WHERE termination_reason IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY country, city, termination_reason
```

I have added the table alias `U` for `user_data_table` in the outer SELECT, so that I can refer to it in the sub-select.

Comment: The problem with the `WHERE` clause in this case is that it won't count the rows where the users are active at all so it will always be `0` there

Comment: Okay I changed that.

Comment: thank you, so I am not sure what's wrong now, might be something else because now it's opposite - I get `0`'s in the active and only numbers on the `non-active`. I assume I have more issues there and I will check again. Might be something the base logic of what I'm trying to achieve and how I display it here

Comment: I edited the post with more data and I think it's clearer

Comment: Okay , I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks, I will check it asap, I have some problems with the db but will check soon

Answer (score 0):

Using your data (and making it a portable table variable)

```
DECLARE @employees TABLE (ID INT, Country NVARCHAR(20), City NVARCHAR(20), TerminationDate DATE, TerminationReason NVARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @employees (ID, Country, City, TerminationDate, TerminationReason) VALUES

(1,'Sweden','Stockholm','2022-10-04','self'),
(2,'Sweden','Stockholm','2020-03-20','admin'),
(2,'Sweden','Stockholm',NULL,NULL),
(3,'Switzerland','Bern',NULL,NULL),
(4,'Switzerland','Bern','2021-12-08','admin'),
(5,'Switzerland','Bern',NULL,NULL)
```

I think this might be what you're looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Country, City, a.TerminationReason, 
       SUM(Active) OVER (PARTITION BY Country, City) AS Active, 
       SUM(Not_Active) OVER (PARTITION BY Country, City, TerminationReason) AS Not_Active
  FROM (
SELECT Country, City, TerminationReason, 
       CASE WHEN TerminationDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Active, 
       CASE WHEN TerminationDate IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Not_Active
  FROM @employees
 WHERE TerminationDate IS NULL
    OR TerminationDate > DATEADD(YEAR,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
      ) a
```

```
Country     City        TerminationReason   Active  Not_Active
--------------------------------------------------------------
Sweden      Stockholm   NULL                1       0
Sweden      Stockholm   self                1       1
Switzerland Bern        NULL                2       0
Switzerland Bern        admin               2       1
```

All we're doing here is excluding the folks terminated over a year ago, and then using windowed aggregates to sum the values across the result set.